# How to relate one custom post type to another custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am coding an exam plugin with following flow:

1. Subject Categories (custom taxonomy)
2. Exams (custom post type) related to subject categories (custom
   taxonomy)
3. MCQ's (custom post type) related to exam (custom post type)

On Adding New MCQ I need to relate it with exams but exams is a post type not taxonomy. How can it be managed?

Comment: I assume MCQ stands for multiple choice question?

Comment: yes MCQ stands for multiple choice question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data organisation is not perfect, which is why you're faced with the current predicament.

Instead of 2 post types and a taxonomy, use 2 taxonomies and 2 post types

1. Subject Categories ( taxonomy )
2. Question Sets ( taxonomy )
3. Exam ( post type )
4. MCQ's ( post type )

Assign MCQ's to a question set, and assign exams to both subject categories and question sets.

When in a subject category archive, list exam post types. When in an exam post, list any MCQ's that share the question set of the current post.

This allows you flexibility, such as sharing questions between exams, changing a question that appears in multiple exams once to fix them all, less unnecessary duplication, etc

In single-exam.php:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'question-sets' );

if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :{

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $q = new WP_Query('post_type' => 'mcq','question-sets' => $term->name);
        if($q->have_posts()){
            while($q->have_posts()){
                $q->the_post();
                get_template_part('single','mcq');
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

Where single-mcq.php contains the html for an individual mcq.

Comment: please explain what will be the 'Question set' in following example: Category-> Database, Exam->Sessional and MCS->What is NF...

Comment: ? Is your comment incomplete? A question set is a grouping of MCQ's, so if I have a maths exam, I have a subject maths, I have an exam post called Maths Exam, I have a question set 'Maths exam questions' and I have MCQ's assigned to that question set